# Integration: $\int \frac {\sin \sqrt {x}}{\sqrt {x}} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integration: $$\int \dfrac {\sin \sqrt {x}}{\sqrt {x}}\, dx$$

My Attempt:
$$\int \dfrac {\sin \sqrt {x}}{\sqrt {x}}\,dx =\int \dfrac {\sin x^{1/2}}{x^{1/2}}\,dx.$$

How do I proceed?

Comment: maybe integrate by parts , you take sin(x^1/2) * x^(-1/2) and see where that goes

Comment: How is that an attempt ?

Comment: @Cursed1701 It's solved easily via a simple substitution.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai, I showed what I get to do!

Comment: @Ramanujan all you did was change the square root symbol for "to the power a half" which is not an attempt. An attempt would be showing a method for solving an integration, following it down that route then posting what you did

Comment: Really MSE! 4 answers basically doing the same thing.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai And the accepted answer was the only one that gave a full, step-by-step, no-self-thought solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:$$\int \frac {\sin \sqrt x}{\sqrt x}~dx$$

$u$ substitution is a technique of integration that allows us to redefine the given integration variable in terms of a different argument, usually denoted as $u$. This is usually helpful when the derivative of some function models closely to your original integral.

---

Consider your problem:

We want to rewrite your integrand $\frac{\sin\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}$ in terms of a simple integral that we already previously know. So consider setting $u=\sqrt x$, thus we have the following:

$$\int \frac {\sin \sqrt x}{\sqrt x}~dx=\int \frac{\sin{u}}{\sqrt x}~dx =\int \frac{\sin{u}}{u}~dx$$

Yet we cannot integrate some variable $u$, with respect to $x$ ($dx$). So find an equation that expresses $dx$, in terms of our newly substituted variable $u$.

Consider taking the derivative of $u$, thus we have:

$$u = \sqrt x=x^{1/2} \Rightarrow \frac {du}{dx}=\frac 12{x^\frac {-1}2} = \frac {1}{2\sqrt x} \Rightarrow dx=2\sqrt x~du$$

Now via substituting our equation for $dx$ in terms of $u$, in the above integral, we now have an integral with respect to the argument $u$.

$2\int \sin(u)\ du = -2\cos(u) + c$ for some constant $c$, upon noting $\int \sin(u)~du = -\cos(u) + c$

Thus by substituting back $u = \sqrt x$, the final answer becomes:

$$\int \frac {\sin \sqrt x}{\sqrt x}~dx=-2\cos\sqrt x +c$$

Comment: How did you do this: " via u substituion, the integral becomes:"? Could you show the steps?

Comment: I made it much more explicit. Note in real analysis, you prove a generalized version of u substitution, for any arbitrary function. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: take $u = \sqrt{x}$, then $2\,\mbox{d}u = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mbox{d}x$.

---

Addendum after comment; with the substitution above, the integral becomes:
$$\int \frac{\sin\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} \,\mbox{d}x \to \int 2\sin u \,\mbox{d}u$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @Ramanujan I updated my answer.

Comment: How is $2du=\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {x}}$?

Comment: @Ramanujan $u = \sqrt{x} \implies \tfrac{du}{dx} = \tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ so...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$d\sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to try is to let $y=\sqrt{x}$ so that $dy = \frac{dx}{2y}$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int\sin y \frac{2y}{y} \,dy= \int \sin y \,dy
$$
and you can take it from there.

Comment: No. Could you please give a basic explanation to each step?

Comment: @MarkFischler $$\int \sin{y}\cdot \frac{2y}{y}~dy=\int \color{red}{2}\sin{y}~dy$$